# Хранение "равнозначных" элементов/атрибутов в xml файле

Tags: c#, xml

Хочу создать настроечный xml файл для приложения на C# в котором будут хранится название свойства, метод с помощью которого реализуется это свойство и параметры для передачи этому методу. Но проблема в том что у различных методов различное количество передаваемых параметров, и если создавать например в таком виде

```
<Param property= "name" method = "name" value1="value" value2="value" ></Param>
<Param property= "name" method = "name" value1="value"></Param>
```

То потом при разборе этой xml много проблем будет с нумерованными атрибутами value. Но и если записывать все параметры в один атрибут, то потом разбирать строку на массив параметров. Как наиболее оптимально поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так:

```
<Params>
    <Param method="method">
       <Props>
         <Item value="value"/>
         <Item value="value"/>
         ...
       </Props>
    </Param>
    ....
</Params>
```

Описание моделей

```
public class Params
{
   public ICollection<Param> Params {get;set;}
}

public class Param
{
   public string Method {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Item> Props {get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
   public object Value {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: а зачем `propname` если параметры неименованные?

Comment: @e1s, это всего лишь пример, а названия хочешь ставь хочешь не ставь, главное принцип

Comment: Тогда все равно не пойму как получить массив значений из этой структуры, допустим object [] , они сохраняют порядок следования?

Comment: @e1s Да, сохраняют, но можете им по желанию добавить поле SortOrder к примеру и по нему отсортировать перед вызовом метода

Comment: @e1s у вас в объекте Param будет коллекция Props которая содержит Item элементы c значениями Value

Comment: Ее для этого десериализовать надо? Не могли бы на примере объяснить?

Comment: @e1s а вы ридером пользовались? лучше конечно десериализовать, получить данные можно будет так `object[] params = Param.Props.Select(a=> new {val = a.value}).ToArray();`

Comment: @e1s десериализация описана тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: если я вас правильно понял создать класс вида `class Container {string Method name{get;set} object[] param {get;set}}` и по куску xml туда засовывать?

Comment: @e1s не совсем, Param тоже надо обернуть. Тоесть должна быть коллекция из Param, по аналогии с тем как сделаны Props, `<Params><Param><Props><Item>.....`, в этом случае вам достаточно десериализовать xml в объект