# Хранение значений List<List<string>> в файле

Tags: c#

Перед запуском приложения необходимо проинициализировать массив `List<List<string>>` значениями из внешнего источника, как наиболее "правильно" это сделать? Использовать xml файл и сериализацию/десериализацию, текстовый файл или есть более красивые "традиционные" решения хранения настроек?

Comment: Settings не пробовали?

Comment: Это вроде как для хранения настроек интерфейса в winforms приложениях

Comment: О каких настройках идёт речь? Можете более точно описать зачем этот список списков строк нужен? Размер его? Откуда берется? Зачем используется? Изменяется ли?

Comment: уже был похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462188/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-xml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5/462193#462193 кстати, от вас же

Comment: @PavelHritonenko не изменяется, надо максимально быстро заполнить массив строками из файла и передать методу

Comment: @e1s то есть из моих вопросов Вы только последний прочитали?

Comment: @PavelHritonenko размер заранее неизвестен, но думаю не более 100 строк, берется он с диска, те уже существует и заполнять его не надо, а на остальные два вопроса я ответил - не изменяется, и передается методу в качестве параметра

Comment: @e1s 100 строк - без разницы. Положите в JSON целиком и целиком считайте.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Правильный, рекомендованный Microsoft путь — хранение данных в `Settings`. Единственная тонкость — в `Settings` непросто вставить нескалярные данные.

Действуем следующим образом:

1. Заходим в свойства проекта, вкладка `Settings`.

   [image: Settings не созданы]
2. Создаём `Settings` по умолчанию, кладём в них свойство `ListOfListsOfStrings`. Как тип мы не можем выбрать `List<List<string>>`, поэтому временно выбираем просто `string`.

   [image: Создали одно свойство]
3. Закрываем проект (важно!), заходим в каталог проекта, открываем файл `Properties\Settings.settings` текстовым редактором. Находим строку наподобие

   ```
   <Setting Name="ListOfListsOfStrings" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
   ```

   вбиваем правильный тип

   ```
   <Setting Name="ListOfListsOfStrings" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;System.String&gt;&gt;" Scope="User">
   ```

   Поскольку мы редактируем XML, нам нужно кодировать `<` и `>` как `&lt;` и `&gt;`.

   [image: Хак через текстовый редактор]
4. Закрываем редактор, снова открываем проект. Находим в проекте файл `Settings.settings` в каталоге `Properties`, выбираем из контекстного меню `Run custom tool`, чтобы перегенерировать `Settings.Designer.cs`.

   [image: Перегенерируем designer.cs]
5. Проект должен компилироваться. Добавляем код, который будет работать с `Settings`:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var settings = ListListSettings.Properties.Settings.Default;
       // при первом пробеге тут ничего нет, создаём
       if (settings.ListOfListsOfStrings == null)
       {
           settings.ListOfListsOfStrings = new List<List<string>>()
           {
               new List<string>() { "1", "2" },
               new List<string>() { "3", "4", "5" } 
           };
           settings.Save();
       }
   }
   ```

Всё!

---

Обновление: вместо логики установки первоначального значения в `Main` можно прописать это самое начальное значение и в `Settings.settings`. Для этого нужно в качестве начального значения во вкладке `Settings` указать вот такую строку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ArrayOfString>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
  </ArrayOfString>
  <ArrayOfString>
    <string>3</string>
    <string>4</string>
    <string>5</string>
  </ArrayOfString>
</ArrayOfArrayOfString>
```

Её нужно именно скопировать в поле ввода `Value`, а не пытаться записать вручную в файл `Settings.settings`, потому что в файле значения `<` и `>` нужно менять на `&lt;` и `&gt;`. Должно получиться что-то такое:

[image: менюшки и кнопочки]

Откуда взять такую хитрую строку? Не придумывать же её самостоятельно? На самом деле, её можно найти, добавив такой код:

```
var sample = new List<List<string>>() // это тот список, который мы раньше
{                                     // записывали в settings.ListOfListsOfStrings
    new List<string>() { "1", "2" },
    new List<string>() { "3", "4", "5" } 
};

var xs = new XmlSerializer(sample.GetType());
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    xs.Serialize(sw, sample);
    var serialized = sw.ToString(); // (*)
}
```

В точке, обозначенной звёздочкой, посмотрите значение переменной `serialized` через отладчик — там будет именно то, что нужно:

[image: выбор визуализатора]
[image: отсюда можно скопировать]

С учётом изменений, код программы упрощается до такого:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var settings = ListListSettings.Properties.Settings.Default;
    var listOfList = settings.ListOfListsOfStrings;
}
```

@Pavel Mayorov, спасибо за подсказку в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @e1s: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Вместо сложной логики установки значения по умолчанию можно было его задать в Settings

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ага, точно. Я тогда не разобрался, как это делать. Сейчас дополню.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, у меня почему-то не выходит, а у вас?

Comment: @VladD Я обычно сохранял объект в файл, копировал значение из него в app.config, после чего позволял студии загрузить "умолчательные" настройки из app.config.

Comment: Достаточно, конечно же, сразу прописать правильную разметку - вот только я постоянно забываю формат :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Уфф, наконец-то проверил, работает :) Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Очень удобный вариант хранения почти любых настроек предлагается проектом [FSharp.Configuration](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/).

Есть несколько основных плюсов использования этого подхода, относительно способа, предложенного @VladD:

1. Настройки будут строготипизированными - типы настроек будут проверяться при компиляции. Имеется в виду, что тип с настройками будет "создан" при компиляции по структуре дефолтного конфига. То есть числа - будут `int`'ами, `00:50:00` - превратится в `TimeSpan` и т.п.
2. Можно использовать формат Yaml - который является понятным, чистым, поддерживает коллекции "из коробки"
3. Не надо загружать и выгружать проект
4. Если не "кэшировать" значение мембера в локальной переменной - то при обращении к `Settings.SomeList` - мы будем всегда иметь актуальное значение (статический экземпляр будет следить за файлом и перечитывать его содержимое).

Пример использования из C# есть на [страничке провайдера](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/YamlConfigProvider.html).

Comment: Круто, не знал. А чем отличается от стандартных `Settings` кроме формата хранения?

Comment: @VladD после использования этой библиотеки, стандартные `Settings` кажутся какой-то неразумной какой. Кроме того, `FSharp.Configuration` поддерживают несколько форматов - AppSettings, ResX, Ini, Yaml.

Comment: По поводу различий: в стандартном варианте настройки тоже строго типизированы. Внутренний формат по идее никому не интересен, абстракция — положили данные, забрали то же при рестарте приложения.

Comment: По поводу пункта 4 мне не кажется это серьёзным достоинством: семантика Settings не предполагает знание пользователя о том, где и как они хранятся, не говоря уже о его активном изменении. Тем более непонятно, что делать с наполовину записанными данными — race condition? А вот третий пункт — несомненный жирный плюс.

Comment: Мы про настройки говорим, или про сериализацию? Настройки  - это то, что можно поправить на сервере в `notepad.exe`

Comment: А как с версионированием? В Settings встроена поддержка версий программы и миграции.

Comment: Стандартные настройки правятся (1) либо перед компиляцией, (2) либо программным путём. Вариант «открыть в блокноте и подправить конфигурацию вручную» не рассматривается, понятно. Пользователь не должен иметь возможность ввести неправильные данные, а в блокноте это запросто.

Comment: Настройки для пользователя надо в любом случае редактировать в UI-диалоге, с валидацией и всем таким.

Comment: В любом случае, пункт 3 важен, редактирование в текстовом редакторе Settings.settings с выгрузкой проекта в моём ответе — позорный хак.

Comment: @VladD редактор для настроек нужен только для мега-форматов вроде XML. Для Yaml оно не нужно. В отличие от "стандартного" способа, если вы для себя не отметили этот момент - класс настроек будет создан на этапе компиляции по формату файла. Я рекомендую просто взять и попробовать это всё сделать в студии - тогда куча вопросов, почему стандартные сеттинги не следует использовать - отпадут сами.

Comment: А, ну так вы бы написали это в тексте ответа (про автогенерацию кода). Это тоже важно же!

Comment: Если кто-то хочет генерировать файл руками — для него FSharp.Configuration. Если через UI с проекте — Settings.

Comment: @VladD дописал, хотя это и не важно в контексте хранения `List<List<string>>`. Ну и в данном случае речь не идет о "кодогенерации", речь идёт о генерации класса на этапе компиляции - используется механизм `TypeProviders`.

Comment: Но всё же первый пункт имеет смысл убрать. Значения для Settings строго типизированы точно так же.

Comment: Поставил бы плюс, но я его поставил раньше.