# Как сохранить список прикрепленных файлов письма в Settings.settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

каким образом можно сохранить коллекцию прикрепленных к письму файлов в Settings.settings (количество прикрепленных файлов может быть любым)? была мысль создать параметр   `List<string>` или  `AttachmentCollection`,но студия не позволяет выбрать ни один из этих типов в колонке "тип".

Comment: Вы ведь хотите сохранять путь до файла, а не файл целиком?

Comment: @Alexey,необходимо сохранять пути к неопределенному(!) количеству файлов. Пользователь может прикрепить один файл ,10 файлов или вообще отправить письмо без вложений.  проблема в сохранении этих путей между сеансами.

Comment: Это уже было, смотрете здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466102/10105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stringCollection = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection { "attachment1", "attachment2" };
        Properties.Settings.Default.Setting = stringCollection;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Единственное что приходит в голову это заполнить StringCollection.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?