# Как добавить в ComboBox список всех стран мира?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Вот встала такая простая задачка, а с ходу не нашел решения.
Конечно можно и в ручную, но это ж как то не по людски..

Comment: Для начала, надо найти список всех стран мира...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Найдите список стран в машиночитаемом формате (xml, json, csv).
2. Добавьте его в приложение как ресурс (Embedded resource)
3. В приложении: загрузите ресурс через `GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(...)` (вызовите в отладчике `GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` если есть затруднения с именем ресурса)
4. Получите из открытого ресурса список стран и передайте его в [`ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) любым удобным методом (прямым присваиванием или через Binding)

Comment: А почему Embedded Resource, а не просто Resource? С ними можно, по идее, проще. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9za7fxc7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @VladD он с файлами некрасиво работает. Вместо того чтобы давать поток - загружает все в массив байт, который в итоге надо самому в MemoryStream оборачивать.

Comment: Там у него же где-то была строгая типизация, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD если использовать строгую типизацию - мы возвращается к проблеме *"Как это все набивать? Вручную что ли?"*. Идея как раз в том, чтобы хранить данные в том формате, к котором смогли найти.

Comment: Ах вот оно что! Ну я в таких случаях не ленюсь написать препроцессор на три строчки, и получаю строки в удобном формате, который можно скормить редактору ресурсов (ну или вручную вбить в файл .resources). Заодно экономится пара миллисекунд в рантайме. Но это уже, наверное, отдельное решение.

Comment: @VladD у нас вот требуют, чтобы подобный препроцессор был приложен к проекту, документирован, и, желательно, участвовал в процессе сборки. Потому что вдруг список стран изменится - а проект передали другому программисту?

Comment: @VladD поэтому некритичные вещи проще делать в рантайме :)

Comment: Ну да, у меня в проекте есть подкаталог с препроцессорами :) Но в процессе сборки он не участвует. (Ну и не всё ли равно, препроцессор в отдельном проекте или в основном?)

Comment: Плюс к тому — не нужно деплоить библиотеки парсера CSV или там JSON.NET. И если парсер налажал, можно подправить руками.

Comment: @VladD, меня очень заинтересовал ваш способ с препроцессором и редактором ресурсов, если я задам такой вопрос вас не затруднить показать подробнее как это вы делаете?

Comment: @Bulson: Ох, я, кажется, перепутал ресурсы и настройки :( С ресурсами вот тут было обсуждение: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466102/10105

Comment: @VladD  я понял OK

Comment: @Bulson: С ресурсами можно добавить текстовый файл, и его содержимое как строка будет доступно по имени (`Properties.Resources.MyTextFile`). Затем эту строку можно, например, разбить по `\n` на куски. Но это будет реально Embedded resource. А вот получить простой текстовый файл из CSV или XML уже можно при помощи препроцессора, вытащив оттуда нужные куски.

Comment: @VladD ознакомился, спасибо.

Comment: @Bulson: Там я как раз дописал улучшение, смотрите снова.

Comment: @VladD хорошо, посмотрю, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Вот [тут](http://country.io/data/) есть все, что Вам нужно. Можете скачать заранее нужный список и работать с ним, можете подгружать его во время запуска приложения, уверен, что на быстродействие Вашего приложения это никак не повлияет.

Раз и навсегда:

```
<ComboBox Height="..." Name="..." Width="...">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
        ...
</ComboBox>
```

Читаем JSON, элементы сохраняем в контейнере, и при запуске приложения:

```
private void Window_Loaded(...)
{
    for_each( ... ) comboBox.Items.Add(...);
}
```

Comment: Вопрос-то не об этом был...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, обновил. Посмотрел Ваш ответ - плюсую, мне он больше нравится.