# Нужно сократить процесс добавления элементов ключ-значение в словарь C#

Tags: c#, рефакторинг, словари

Ну у меня есть словарь - и нужно проинициализировать элементы, добавить пару в словарь но таким громадным способом как-то на говнокодера себя смотрю (мб так и есть) как можно этот процесс сократить?

```
public void InitializeLatters()//Своя буква свое кол-во очков!
    {
        latterScore.Add('а', 1);
        latterScore.Add('б', 2);
        latterScore.Add('в', 1);
        latterScore.Add('г', 3);
        latterScore.Add('д', 2);
        latterScore.Add('е', 1);
        latterScore.Add('ё', 3);
        latterScore.Add('ж', 5);
        latterScore.Add('з', 5);
        latterScore.Add('и', 1);
        latterScore.Add('й', 4);
        latterScore.Add('к', 2);
        latterScore.Add('л', 2);
        latterScore.Add('м', 2);
        latterScore.Add('н', 1);
        latterScore.Add('о', 1);
        latterScore.Add('п', 2);
        latterScore.Add('р', 1);
        latterScore.Add('с', 1);
        latterScore.Add('т', 1);
        latterScore.Add('у', 2);
        latterScore.Add('ф', 10);
        latterScore.Add('х', 5);
        latterScore.Add('ц', 5);
        latterScore.Add('ч', 5);
        latterScore.Add('ш', 8);
        latterScore.Add('ь', 3);
        latterScore.Add('ы', 5);
        latterScore.Add('э', 8);
        latterScore.Add('ъ', 10);
        latterScore.Add('ю', 8);
        latterScore.Add('я', 3);
        latterScore.Add('*', 0);
    }
```

Comment: если по букве посчитать количество очков нет возможности, то вы можете воспользоваться инициализатором словаря или залить все это в конфиги

Comment: На примере можно? Не понятно, в программировании не так давно

Comment: добавил вариант с инициализатором. Вариант с конфигом добавлять смысла нет наверное, если вы новичек в программировании - то вам скорее всего конфиг не нужен.

Comment: Замечание: наверно всё-таки должно быть `letter`.

Comment: Спасибо - Учту!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А я бы всё-таки вынес данные из кода, желательно в отдельный файл, но для начала можно хотя бы так:

```
var data = "а-1;б-2;в-1;г-3;д-2;е-1;ё-3;ж-5;з-5;и-1;й-4;к-2;л-2;м-2;н-1;о-1;п-2;р-1;с-1;т-1;у-2;ф-10;х-5;ц-5;ч-5;ш-8;ь-3;ы-5;э-8;ъ-10;ю-8;я-3;*-0";
var letterScore = data.Split(';')
                      .Select(d => d.Split('-'))
                      .ToDictionary(pair => char.Parse(pair[0]),
                                    pair => int.Parse(pair[1]));
```

Берем строку, разбиваем ее по `;`, потом эти кусочки каждый в отдельности разбиваем по `-`, часть до дефиса берем в качестве ключа, а после дефиса — в качестве значения словаря.

Comment: Вы бы стали этот код использовать в проде?

Comment: Почему бы и нет?

Comment: блин уже гдето видел синтаксис просто точки и команды. Но информации найти не могу. Можете обяснить недалёкому что это значит(и выражение "=>")

Comment: @AquaGF, это Linq и лямбда-выражения (анонимные методы) в параметрах. Читайте литературу, позволяет сильно упростить код.

Comment: Это не просто точки, это цепочка методов, обратите внимание, строка не завершается точкой с запятой. Называется Fluent API

Comment: Я просто начал недавно переосмысливать свой код с точки зрения поддерживаемости \ читаемости и прочее, набрал литературы и зарылся в неё по уши, потому не считайте за придирку, просто хочу ваше мнение понять. Вот я смотрю на ваш код - что он должен по сути делать? Создавать словарь. Но он помимо прочего сздает магическую строку, парсит, обрабатывает её. Причем имхо строка в таком формате, что нужную букву надо искать глазами - что не так удобно в сравнении даже с кодом в вопросе автора.

Comment: То есть код вроде бы и стал короче, но при этом он стал сложнее, труднее для чтения и понимания, и ошибку в такой строке сделать гораздо проще, чем в инициализаторе или прямом добавлении в словарь. Так ещё и код помимо самой инициализации делает не относящиеся к ней вещи типа парсинга, который тут по сути не нужен

Comment: Ну, и, конечно, с парсингом код будет работать ещё и медленней, хотя это не важно в данном случае.

Comment: Мне было бы все ясно, допустим, если бы строка бралась из конфига - тут вопросов нет, в этом случае парсинг уместен. Или все ясно когда задействован инициализатор напрямую. Но у вас получается код между двумя вариантами - не инициализатор, и не конфиг. Хотя минусы собирает и от обоих случаев - парсин от конфига и хардкод от инициализатора

Comment: Может я сильно заморочился и меня понесло, сорри :) Но эти мысли и были причиной моего первого вопроса про использования этого кода в проде. Коллеги говорят, что я жестко сильно отношусь к ревью - может, оно так и есть. Интересно было бы узнать ваше мнение.

Comment: @tym32167, ага, я понял вас, тут я скорее согласен, потому и написал "для начала". В итоге надо выносить в отдельный файл и вместо точек с запятой, конечно же, использовать переводы строк. Но мое мнение по поводу того что код должен быть отделен от данных не изменилось, поэтому инициализация словаря в этом смысле плоха тем, что она будет где-то замешана в коде (ну и нельзя данные поменять без перекомпиляции проекта, если это, конечно, надо). В любом случае, не устану напоминать, что я не специалист и не имею опыта "промышленной разработки" :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага, ну то есть мы таки в одном направлении мыслим. Спасибо! `я не специалист и не имею опыта "промышленной разработки"` - :D да да

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с инициализатором словаря (я так понял, метод инициализирует ваш словарик один раз)

```
public void InitializeLatters()//Своя буква свое кол-во очков!
{
    latterScore = new Dictionary<char, int>() {
        {'a', 1},
        {'б', 2},
        {'в', 1},
        {'г', 3},
        {'д', 2},
        {'е', 1},
        {'ё', 3},
        {'ж', 5},
        {'з', 5},
        {'и', 1},
        {'й', 4},
        {'к', 2},
        {'л', 2},
        {'м', 2},
        {'н', 1},
        {'о', 1},
        {'п', 2},
        {'р', 1},
        {'с', 1},
        {'т', 1},
        {'у', 2},
        {'ф', 1},
        {'х', 5},
        {'ц', 5},
        {'ч', 5},
        {'ш', 8},
        {'ь', 3},
        {'ы', 5},
        {'э', 8},
        {'ъ', 1},
        {'ю', 8},
        {'я', 3},
        {'*', 0},       
    };  
}
```

Comment: Да всего один раз. Щас попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Сначала не заработало, по 1 очку добавляло (у меня тестовые буквы были а и ф) а вы опечатались там где десять очков там написано 1 (ф,ъ) а так всё отлично работает спасибо.

Comment: Ну если ещё идеи есть то пишите.

Comment: Возможно, будет немного нагляднее, если использовать специальный инициализатор для словарей: `['a'] = 1`

Comment: В конфигурации приложения можно добавить тип *Collection, вот это все разумно унести туда, можно создать 2 коллекции например, с буквами и значениями, перебрать for, for each или linq.. В общем море вариантов, и код не захломляет.

Comment: @NewView, при желании в конфигурации можно и словарь засунуть.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, как любопытно :) переопределить чего то как пользовательский тип?

Comment: @NewView, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466102/218063 думаю, для словаря тоже сработает

Comment: Хотя, если в основе Settings лежит xml-сериализация, может не получиться просто так, придется хранить в каком-то промежуточном виде

Comment: Спасибо, интересно